# How to merge css in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to merge all css into one file. I can do manually but I don't understand last argument of `wp_register_style`.

From laptop it's load all css.

```
        wp_register_style('desktop-small-css', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/desktop.small.css','','','(max-width:'.get_option($dynamo_tpl->name . '_theme_width', '1230').'px)');
        wp_enqueue_style('desktop-small-css');

        wp_register_style('tablet-css', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/tablet.css','','','(max-width:'.get_option($dynamo_tpl->name . '_tablet_width', '1030').'px)');
        wp_enqueue_style('tablet-css');

        wp_register_style('tablet-small-css', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/tablet.small.css','','','(max-width:'.get_option($dynamo_tpl->name . '_small_tablet_width', '820').'px)');
        wp_enqueue_style('tablet-small-css');

        wp_register_style('mobile-css', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/mobile.css','','','(min-width:'.get_option($dynamo_tpl->name . '_mobile_width', '580').'px)');
        wp_enqueue_style('mobile-css');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style,

I guess it's a mediaquery, find out which stylesheet is for which device and remove/edit the `$media` option.
It might be a lot easier to remove the `$media` option of all `wp_register_style` and add `@media()` media queries inside your stylesheets.